# Load TinyMCE using innerHTML in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

Based on a selected option the code prints an *textarea* on the *complemento1* div:

```
        if ($_GET["t"]==1) /// Text
    {
        $str="";
        $str.="<table width=100%>";
            $str.="<tr>";
                $str.="<td>";
                    $str.="Digite aqui o texto que será exibido:";
                $str.="</td>";
            $str.="<tr>";
                $str.="<td>";
                    $str.="<textarea id='texto' name='texto' rows=3 cols=80>".$row["texto"]."</textarea>";
                $str.="</td>";
        $str.="</table>";
        echo "<script>window.parent.document.getElementById('complemento1').innerHTML=\"".$str."\";</script>";
    }
```

Now I want to add an TinyMCE editor, but my attempts failed, I've tried to put the code on the PHP file:

```
    <script src="/_assets/editor/vendor/tinymce/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">tinymce.init({mode: 'textareas', language: 'pt_BR', menubar: '', statusbar: false});</script>
```

Despite "Mode: textareas" nothing happens... If I call the init inside my code:

```
<script>window.parent.document.getElementById('complemento1').innerHTML=\"".$str."\"; tinymce.init({mode: 'textareas', language: 'pt_BR', menubar: '', statusbar: false});</script>
```

Got the error on the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
at
```

^^^ It is already defined on my PHP! ( at head)

Where did I go wrong? How can I define TinyMCE correctly?

Comment: Obviously `tinymce` was not defined, i.e. not loaded. See network console.

Comment: I would recommend you to use ckeditor... it's awesome! the implementation is easier. take a look: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone i've edited the question, asking how ca I define it. Since it is working on all other textareas.
Can you help me with that?

Comment: @MiguelCruz thanks for the suggestion, willl take a try on ckeditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to **load tinymce in the beginning** and try to open it to **check if  exist**

`<script src="/_assets/editor/vendor/tinymce/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>`

or try to run your JS after loading code :

```
$('#complemento1').html(\"".$str."\").promise().done(function( arg1 ) {
  //  try fire the event here  
 tinymce.init({mode: 'textareas', language: 'pt_BR', menubar: '', statusbar: false})
});
```

you can also try to add document.ready function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#complemento1').html(\"".$str."\").promise().done(function( arg1 ) {
     //  try fire the event here  
    tinymce.init({mode: 'textareas', language: 'pt_BR', menubar: '', statusbar: false})
    });
});
```